# How do I display two different views for a single content?

Tags: views, nodes

I'm quite new to drupal and trying to learn this after working with a very different CMS system the past ten years.  Here is my issue/question:

I have a content type that I'd like to have two distinctly different views. The first view contains a form (that does not use any drupal module).  When a user submits the form, I'd like to show a 'confirmation page' view for that same content type (since it has info that I'd like to show in the confirmation view).  What would be the url to use for the different view?

Comment: define "the different view"

Comment: you need extra info being displayed when the user submit the form or new structure of the displayed node

Comment: New structure of displayed node.  Example - one CTD, one content, two different views.  The second view would have different verbiage, layout than the view containing the form.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a module for your form in this content type, there is no other way. (unless you want something complicated within an iFrame).

Either write a custom module yourself, or use the usual [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module

Comment: It should not matter.  That is irrelevant if I use their form or make a module.  All I am asking is how to create two distinct pages using the same content and how would the URL be defined?